# Can't remove new added HTML elements after a timeOut

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I try to create a Google material "ripple" effect, without any library. For that I have used [Sitepoint's script for capturing CSS3 Animation](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-animation-javascript-event-handlers/) and a script to "emulate" jQuery's offset method:

```
function offset(elt) {
    var rect = elt.getBoundingClientRect(), bodyElt = document.body;
    return {
        top: rect.top + bodyElt.scrollTop,
        left: rect.left + bodyElt.scrollLeft
    }
}
```

I take exemple from [Hai Nguyen react touch-ripple file](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/js/ripples/touch-ripple.jsx) for animation but I don't know even basics of react so I made something like his code mostly for animation. My problem is that for the effect I add a new `<span>`, after all modification finished and remove the old one after a 1 second delay, for one click it's working well, but if I click several times new `<span>` elements are still here. I'm far from being a JS guru. So if you see a big mistake, just tell me and I'm gonna improve my code. All code together HTML, SCSS and JS are visible [here](http://codepen.io/AlexanderDom/pen/ByPQLy). 
My HTML:

```
<button>
    <span class="ripples">
        <span class="ripples-circle"></span>
    </span>Test
</button>
<button>
    <span class="ripples">
        <span class="ripples-circle"></span>
    </span>Test
</button>
<button>
    <span class="ripples">
        <span class="ripples-circle"></span>
  </span>Test
</button>
<button>
    <span class="ripples">
    <span class="ripples-circle"></span>
  </span>Test
</button>
<button class="round">
    <span class="ripples">
        <span class="ripples-circle"></span>
    </span>Test
</button>
```

My SCSS (I use Autoprefixer):

```
body { /*just for remove inline-block lateral margins*/
    font-size: 0;
}

button {
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 4em;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: gray;
    border-style:solid;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 12px 24px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms;

&.round {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
&:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

&:hover {
    background-color: darken(gray, 5%);
}
}

.ripples {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    background-color: transparent;
    opacity: 0.7;
    transition: opacity 1s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms;

    &.is-active {
        opacity: 1;
        .ripples-circle {
              -webkit-transform: scale(1);
              transform: scale(1);
        }
    }

    .ripples-circle {
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
        transform: scale(0);
        transition: -webkit-transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms;
        transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms;
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
;(function(window, document, undefined){
    'use strict';
    //http://www.debray-jerome.fr/js-performance-la-fonction-offset-de-jquery-vs-vanilla-javascript-23.html -- french
    function offset(elt) {
        var rect = elt.getBoundingClientRect(), bodyElt = document.body;
        return {
            top: rect.top + bodyElt.scrollTop,
            left: rect.left + bodyElt.scrollLeft
        }
    }

    //http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-animation-javascript-event-handlers/

    var pfx = ["webkit", "moz", "MS", "o", ""];
    function prefixedEvent(element, type, callback) {
        for (var p = 0; p < pfx.length; p++) {
            if (!pfx[p]) type = type.toLowerCase();
            element.addEventListener(pfx[p]+type, callback, false);
    }
}

function calcDiag(a, b) {
    return Math.sqrt((a * a) + (b * b));
}

    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
    for(var i=0; i < buttons.length;i++ ){
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){

        var rippleThis = this;
        var parentOffset = offset(rippleThis);
        var elHeight = rippleThis.offsetHeight;
        var elWidth = rippleThis.offsetWidth;
        var pageX = e.pageX == undefined ? e.nativeEvent.pageX : e.pageX;
        var pageY = e.pageY == undefined ? e.nativeEvent.pageY : e.pageY;
        var x = pageX - parentOffset.left;
        var y = pageY - parentOffset.top;

        var topLeftDiag = calcDiag(x, y);
        var topRightDiag = calcDiag(elWidth - x, y);
        var botRightDiag = calcDiag(elWidth - x, elHeight - y);
        var botLeftDiag = calcDiag(x, elHeight - y);
        var rippleRadius = Math.max(topLeftDiag, topRightDiag, botRightDiag, botLeftDiag);
        var rippleSize = rippleRadius * 2;

        var j;
        var childrenLength = rippleThis.childNodes.length;
        var targetParent;
        var targetChild;

        for(j = 0; j < childrenLength; j++){
          if(rippleThis.childNodes[j].className == 'ripples') {
            targetParent = rippleThis.childNodes[j];
            targetParent.style.top = (y - rippleRadius) + 'px';
            targetParent.style.left = (x -rippleRadius) + 'px';
            targetParent.style.height = rippleSize +'px';
            targetParent.style.width = rippleSize +'px';
            targetParent.className = 'ripples is-active';
          }
        }

       //New span element
       var rippleSpan = document.createElement('span');
       var rippleCircleSpan = document.createElement('span');
       rippleSpan.className = "ripples";
       rippleCircleSpan.className = "ripples-circle";
       //Add new span
       rippleSpan.appendChild(rippleCircleSpan);
       rippleThis.insertBefore(rippleSpan, rippleThis.childNodes[0]);
    }, false);
    buttons[i].addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){
      prefixedEvent(e.currentTarget, "TransitionEnd", function(e){
      var button = e.currentTarget;
        for(var j = 0; j < button.childNodes.length; j++){
          if(button.childNodes[j].className == 'ripples is-active') {
            var targetParent = button.childNodes[j];
            targetParent.style.opacity = 0;
            setTimeout(function(){
              if(targetParent.parentNode){ targetParent.parentNode.removeChild(targetParent);             
              }
            }, 1000);

          }
        }
    });
    }, false);
}
})(window, document);
```

Final effect that I want is visible [here](http://callemall.github.io/material-ui/#/components/buttons).

Comment: I work with these guys. Let me know if you don't get an answer by tomorrow and I will ping one of them to help you.

Comment: @chapinkapa as you see no answers, so if you can thank you

Comment: Alright, I'll ask them

Comment: The TBBT fiddle deserves a +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've founded solution to my problem. Working script is visible [here](http://codepen.io/AlexanderDom/pen/ByOXqO).
I've moved my prefixed event upper in the code, before it was a separate `eventListener` for `mouseup` event and more important i call it on parent `span` element, before it was on `button` itself, that's why event don't work. And i've added one more condition to `setTimeOut` condition :

Before

```
if(targetParent.parentNode){
```

After

```
if(targetParent && targetParent.parentNode){
```

So now my code works, and `span`s disappear from `DOM`

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell from your linked site, visually this works quite well and the problem is your leftover spans. I believe your problem is actually `closure` and doesn't have anything to do with react. I had a similar issue (in a completely different environment, but the basics were the same) recently and I've solved it by removing the timeout and using an interval that checked for timeout conditions. This is pretty much how it works:

Have a javascript variable that keeps an array of all active elements with the time they were created. Every 1 second loop all elements and see if their timers have already expired. If so, remove them.

This is clearly not the most efficient solution as it requires (almost) constant checking for elements, but it will certainly work. If this isn't implemented in a performance intensive environment, it should perform quite well.

Also, if you find another solution, I'd be happy to see if I can implement as well.